# Why won't my assets load in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

It's the first time I've tried to put a Rails application on a server running in production mode without using EngineYard in a couple of years. There is probably a whole lot I don't remember. This is version 4.2.5.

I'm not deploying with Capistrano, I'm not going through all that trouble right now. This is an internal-facing application for my team. I'm simply pulling down the code from Github when I update something. Very simple.

The app comes up no problem. And I ran:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

But ALL of the assets yield a 404. Only my raw application comes up.

I'm not even trying to run Nginx right now. Whether I run Webrick or try to start a Unicorn process, I get no CSS.

And yet, all the files that are showing 404's, I see them very, very clearly in:

```
<app root>/public/assets
```

Are Webrick and Unicorn unable to serve up those assets for some strange reason? If so, what reason could that be? Do I need to do a full deploy using Nginx and Passenger on a simple, internal-facing, nothing of an app?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as others have said, please check that you are running in production mode ? Secondly, you mentioned that you are running in WEBrick. Is `config.serve_static_files` set to `true` ?

> config.serve_static_files configures Rails itself to serve static
>   files. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned
>   off as the server software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the
>   application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
>   setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
>   testing your app in production mode using WEBrick

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Comment: The default setting in 4.2.5 for the production environment is: ```  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```. I had not set that environment variable. As soon as I did, it worked. Thank you very, very kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You must write

```
$rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Also you must set to `config_assets_precompile = true` to config/initializers/assets.rb file

Also try therubyracer gem.

Answer (score -1):

The lack of CSS/JS would suggest that your assets aren't being loaded in production (obviously).

The way to fix it is either to use what `Ruby Doggy` recommended (and precompile the assets prior to pushing to production), or using something like a `post-receive` hook to achieve the same.

One important factor to consider is which `environment variables` you have set. I've never used `Engine Yard`, but `Heroku` sets the `RAILS_ENV` var for each app:

[image]

If I were you, I would set the `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` variables in your production env OS:

```
EXPORT RAILS_ENV=production
EXPORT RACK_ENV=production
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/731

This will set the env vars, which *should* allow you to invoke `rake assets:precompile` after push to get the correct assets.